# Can a class specialize a template class and inherit from it at the same time?

Tags: c++, polymorphism

Let's say I have a template base class that looks like this:

```
template <typename T>
class Base
{
    public:
         virtual void somefunc() =0;
};
```

I want to make a concrete derived class, for which of course I would need to implement `somefunc`. I could do it like this:

```
class Derived : public Base<int>
{
    public:
        virtual void somefunc() { std::cout << "hello\n";}
        void otherfunc() {std::cout << "Hello\n";}
};
```

But this creates an annoyance when I try to expose these things to Python via Boost Python. Even though I've only defined two classes here, `Base` and `Derived`, I need to explicitly expose `Base<int>` to Python, even though I'll never instantiate it. What I'm wondering is, is there some way I can inherit from the template class at the same time that I instantiate it? Essentially, can I treat Base as a derived class of Base?

Comment: Maybe I've misunderstood the question, but I think you might be confused. `Base` is not a class. It's a class template. `Base<int>` is a class, in fact an abstract class so you can't create complete objects whose type is `Base<int>`, but you *will* create instances of it when you create instances of `Derived` (the base class subobject).

Comment: I think you understood the question correctly, it just seems that the answer is that it is not possible. Please go ahead and turn your comment into an answer if you like

Comment: well, it is possible for one specialization of a class template to declare another specialization of the same class template as a base class. I just don't think doing that would solve anything. So I actually don't know how to answer the question you asked, hence only making a comment :-)

Comment: You mean doing something like `class Base<int> : public Base<double>`? Yea, that doesn't quite solve this the way I would like, but then that just means that's how the language works. In that case, so be it! I've come up with a bit of a better way to expose these things to Python anyway with some templated functions that can hide some this annoyance.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a type that represents `Base<int>` using a `typedef`

```
typedef BaseInt Base<Int>;
```

You should be able to use `BaseInt` in however you are exporting your information to Boost Python.

Answer (score 0):

You can just specialize the template if you don't need the interface class.

```
// No definition required
template <typename T>
class Base;

// Specialization
template <>
class Base<int> {
    public:
        virtual void somefunc();
        void otherfunc();
}
```

Comment: Well, I want to create several specializations of `Base`, and I want them all to implement a particular function, that's why I have `somefunc` defined as pure virtual in my question. This doesn't seem like it would allow that.

Comment: @Nickolai Does `somefunc()`'s return type depend on the template parameter?

Comment: In my actual code, as opposed to this toy example, yes it does. Actually, I think that this breaks down anyway, because I can't have a pointer to Base. So I can't use a Base pointer to call myfunc on some specialization of it...

Comment: @Nickolai I agree. You are responsible to provide an interface in that case.